# Grid columns wont fit content

Tags: css, webview, css-grid

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  height: 900px;
  width: 100%;
}

#grid > section {
  border: 2px solid cyan;
}

#grid > section > div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 80%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
      <section>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div></div>
      </section>
    </div>
```

In this snippet, the blue boxes are not fitting to the req squares inside of them.

I want the width of the blue rectangle to match the red boxes - the blue rectangles currently have an auto width.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

---

One interesting thing is if I set (in dev tools)

```css
    #grid > section {
      width: max-content;
    }
```

Then the issue is temporarily fixed, until I reload the page (with `width: max-content` still set), then it's back to being broken like above; so it only fixes on an update (but not initial rendering). This makes me think maybe this is a CSS rendering bug
[image]

Comment: The problem appears to be that the grid layout algorithm establishes the width of the columns before it gets to the `aspect-ratio` of nested elements. Not sure there's a way around this with CSS. It's the rendering sequence.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin So it's indeed a rendering engine issue?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes. You would have to get into the technical details to know for sure. But that's probably unnecessary, as the behavior appears to be the same across all major browsers.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin Do you have any idea for the best work-around? I can't think of any

Comment: If allowable, re-work the HTML. Perhaps one level of nesting instead of two. Otherwise, a JS hack.